# jarsigner manifest permissions

Tags: java, parameters, manifest, jarsigner, java-web-start

How can you add additional parameters to a jar's manifest file when signing it? I have a javaws app that uses some external libraries. Starting with java7u25 there is a need for additional parameters in the manifest (permissions and codebase). How can I set these at signing (with maven if possible). I can set it at build time for the artifacts I produce but for the ones I get from the external repositories how can I insert them at signing time?

Comment: I solved this by implementing a custom maven plugin that apart from getting the jars from the repository will also inject the required manifest entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I update the 3rd party jars prior to signing them.
The ant task for updating the jar is:

jar ufm thirdparty.jar manifest_adder.mf

- u: update
- f: output to file
- m: manifest file attached.

The manifest_adder.mf file will be merged with the existing manifest in the 3rd party jar.

Comment: I selected yours as the answer even though I used a (technically) different approach (but the main idea is the same) since there is no way than doing it without this additional step (before/after signing).

Answer (score 3):

Important observation:

Note: The contents of the manifest must be encoded in UTF8.

I lost a lot of time because of that. Hope this help someone.

Comment: Valid ASCII is also valid UTF8, so typically this shouldn't be a problem; can you elaborate on what you had to do to make it work?

Comment: I've just opened the Manifest.mf with windows notepad and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about maven, but i recently researched on this topic regarding appending the same attributes(those you mentioned) to third party jars at build time using **ANT**. The procedure in Java is creating another Manifest file(containing the new attributes) and appending it with the Manifest of the jar.You can check the command [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html). I was creating my jars at build time so i had two options:

First:
1) Unzip the jar
2) Modify Manifest
3) Create the Jar again

but this was quite cumbersome so i used `exec()` [task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) of ANT to run the command for merging the two manifest.

Hope this resolves your problem. Thanks